# notepad++ change delimiter only between text

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to change a delimiter between an existing one.

Example:

Text:

```
"20;05;01";KT;1;467;331;1360
```

I want to change it to:

```
"20,05,01";KT;1;467;331;1360
```

Comment: Did you try [regular expressions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions) ?

Comment: im pretty new to regex if yould make an example for the above would be nice.

Comment: Does the text in first delimiters allows contain 3 numbers?

Comment: Yes there are always 3 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a search/replace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) with the mode of search set to regular expressions.

Search pattern: `"(.*);(.*);(.*)"(.*)`

Replace pattern: `"\1,\2,\3"\4`

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

**This will work for any number of semicolon inside double quotes.**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:"|\G)(?:(?![;"]).)*\K;(?=.*?")`
- Replace with: `,`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:"|\G)        # non capture group, a double quote OR restart from last match position
(?:             # non capture group
  (?![;"])        # negative lookahead, make sure the next character is not semicolon or double quote
  .               # any character
)*              # end group, may appear 0 or more times
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
;               # semicolon
(?=.*?")        # positive lookahead, make sure we have a double quote after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]